# C++ Vector push / pop

Tags: c++, vector

I've been looking all over for a solution to this. Not using c++11.

```
for(int a = 1; a < team1.chan; a++)
{
        team1.nums.push_back(ppb.back());
        ppb.pop_back();

        cout << team1.nums[a] << " " << endl;
}
```

**ppb** is an uns int vector with 1-1000 that have been shuffled. 
**team1** is a struct with nums as an uns int vector.

I'm trying to take the last number in **ppb** and assign it to the first number in **team1.nums**.
Then I need to delete that value in **ppb** so I have no duplicates.

I printed the actual numbers in ppb and they are fine. When I compile I get about 40 numbers like 2397295 then about 80 zeroes.

I am slowly getting C++, but vectors are killing me. Thank you.

Comment: try `for(int a =` **0** `; a < team1.chan; a++)`

Comment: Why is `a` starting from 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vectors are zero indexed but your 'a' starts at 1.

So the first value from `ppb.back()` is stored at `team1.nums[0]` but you print `team1.nums[1]`.
The next value from `ppb.back()` is stored at `team1.nums[1]` but now you print `team1.nums[2]`.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that in C++ (and most other compiled programming languages) indices start from zero rather than one, so you'd get exactly the same problem if you were reading elements from an array - a ten element array has entries from 0..9 not 1..10

Comment: Hahahaha. I'm an idiot. What's really dumb is that in the test to print out ppb I have it at 0 to display correctly. Thanks for letting me see something I should have seen.

Answer (score 0):

Try to loop using

```
while(ppb.empty() == false)
{
...// Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that all you need is

```
team1.nums.assign( std::make_move_iterator( team1.rbegin() ), std::make_move_iterator( team1.rend() ) );
team1.clear();
```

Or if the move constructor is not supported then

```
team1.nums.assign( team1.rbegin(), team1.rend() );
team1.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use iterators when using containers. It will avoid such indexing errors. Also you have access to some neat functions like std::copy which puts all the copy code you wrote in just one line.

```
std::copy(ppb.rbegin(),ppb.rend(),back_inserter(team1.nums));
```

`back_inserter` uses the `vector::push_back` so you dont have to reserve the space